# Python.exe not respongding when run in interactive shell, in use with pygame

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm making a game using the default Python IDLE and Pygame. I am creating a simple cat animation  but there is a problem when I try to run the module. A black screen just appears and the heading just says 'Animation NOT RESPONDING', below I have listed the code used for this animation. Thanks for the help! 
Thanks, just edited it, does this look better?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
catImg = pygame.image.load('cat.png')
catx = 10
caty = 10
direction = 'right'

while True: # the main game loop
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    if direction == 'right':
        catx += 5
        if catx == 280:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty += 5
        if caty == 220:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -= 5
        if caty == 10:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -= 5
        if caty == 10:
            direction = 'right'
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(catImg, (catx, caty))

            for event in pygame.eventget():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.exit()
                    sys.exit()

            pygame.display.update()
            fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I can't see any problems, btw i'm new. Please point out where?:)

Comment: If you look at your question, you can see that all the tabs/indents are missing, making your code unrunnable. And if it's not possible to run the code, it's not possible for anybody to help you. (You can click "edit" in the lower-left of your question to make changes to your post.)

Comment: Getting the indentation right is especially important in a case where the problem may well be that the `update` function is outside of the event loop instead of inside of it…

Comment: Thanks for all the input, I've changed it so hopefully its better.

Comment: @PixelPuppet -- did you mean to have the event-handling/display updating/clock code indented that far to the right? If so, then that might be your problem, since the event/display/clock code should generally be indented only once so they're run with every iteration of the `while` loop

Comment: Thanks so much for this but I made a typo when I wrote 'pygame.eventget():' when it should have been: 'pygame.event.get():'

Answer (score 1):

You can re-edit your posts for typos, there's a link at the end.

The problem is event handling never is ran, unless both `direction == 'up'` and `caty == 10`. The window then stops responding, since it can't get messages.

```
while True: # the main game loop
    # events 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.exit()
            sys.exit()

    # movement
    # ... snip ...

    # drawing
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(Color("white"))

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(catImg, (catx, caty))

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```